# Adding values from small matrix to a specific place in larger matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a question regarding matrices in numpy, I'm pretty new to using it. To simplify my problem: Say I have a "large" 4x4 matrix `A` consisting of zeros and a smaller 2x2 matrix `B` consisting on ones. I want to add `B` to specific indices in `A`. I want to end up with the ones on row[1], col [1]; row[1] col[3]; row[3] col[1] and row[3] col[3] in A. I have an array with the indices `arr` = [1,3]. How do I add this matrix B to matrix A given array `arr`?

```
A = [[0,0,0,0], 
     [0,0,0,0], 
     [0,0,0,0], 
     [0,0,0,0]]

B = [[1,1], 
     [1,1]]

arr = [1,3]

Desired result: A = 
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,1]]
```

Thankful for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `arr` is both rows and columns indices, you need to extract a view on the submatrix containing rows 1 and 3 and columns 1 and 3. Here is the simplest way, using [numpy advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
A = np.zeros((4, 4))
B = np.ones((2, 2))
arr = np.array([1, 3])

A[arr[:, None], ar] += B
```

`arr[:, None]` is just a shortcut for `arr.reshape(-1, 1)`. It means the indices refer explicitly to the rows.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Another way that i found was to use the numpy.ix_ command as well